# SQLite Manager 0.8.3.1 - How do I delete a Query?

Tags: sqlite

How do I delete a Query in SQLite 0.8.3.1 ?

I have looked in the manual.  The closest I see is how to "do" a Delete Query . . . https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_delete_query.htm

Comment: What do you mean by "delete" a query?

Comment: Do you mean to stop a query that is currently running?

Comment: There is no version 0.8.3.1.

Comment: This Add-on for Firefox, sorry . . . SQLite Manager . . . https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: Your question is totally wrong. You asked `How do I delete a query?`, but you actually wanted to ask `How do I run a DELETE command?`

Comment: False.  The question is valid.  I wanted to know how to delete a Query . . . It looks like the easiest way is to manually delete it by going to the Table . . . The more complex way is to get the correct syntax to run a Delete command, and then, figure out where you place it, and how to run it . . . I have used Access before, but never SQLite Manager, which has a different layout than I'm used to.  I haven't spent much time learning about it, or using it, that's why this was a big question I had.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out from this page:

https://github.com/lazierthanthou/sqlite-manager/wiki/Execute-SQL-Tab

At the bottom, it says to run this in the "Enter SQL" box:

`DELETE FROM __sm_ext_mgmt WHERE type = "NamedQuery:` *`query_name"`*

The syntax / grave accent / low line were confusing me.

This page helped, I see those are not used . . . https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/delete.php

---

This is what I typed in, and ran, to delete the query:

DELETE FROM __sm_ext_mgmt WHERE type = "NamedQuery:Bookmarks export"

"NamedQuery:Bookmarks export" appears as a row in the table . . . __sm_ext_mgmt

---

I think I could have just gone to the table . . . __sm_ext_mgmt

. . . clicked on the "Browse & Search" tab, and right-clicked to delete the query with no worries - it's a database, right? - that would be simpler, no need to run any code

---

A "Query History" remains in the table . . . __sm_ext_mgmt

To clean up, go to the "Execute SQL" tab, and click the "Trash Can" icon to "Clear Query History"